# Grab and display filtered values of jQuery isotope with select option, in external page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, jquery-isotope

I have 2 pages - apple.php & red-apples.php

apples.php

**HTML**

```
<select class="filters-select">
    <option value=".a1">a1</option>
    <option value=".a2">a2</option>
</select>
<div class="isotope">//values to be filtered here, with itemSelector class each</div>
```

**JS**

```
// bind filter on select change
$('.filters-select').on('change', function () {
    // get filter value from option value
    var filterValue = this.value;
    // use filterFn if matches value
    filterValue = filterFns[filterValue] || filterValue;
    $container.isotope({
        filter: filterValue
    });
});
```

Now I want red-apples.php, to load / open / echo on load, with a div say

red-apples.php

```
<div id="grab-filtered-data">

// filtered-data-of isotope from apples.php, when a1 is selected

</div>
```

Any clues ?

Comment: Clue is :

red-apples.php

    <head>

     <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#grab-filtered-data').load('apples.php .isotope');
            });
            </script>


</head>

    <body>

    <div id="grab-filtered-data">
    </div>


    </body>